# Clion. Configure CMakeLists.txt auto adding sources and header paths

Tags: cmake, clion

Am i able to configure clion to add newly created sources and headers as cmake variable.

Example:
I have a project hierarchy as that

```
src
- sources
- headers
- CMakeLists.txt (Target) (1*)
CMakeLists.txt (Some default configs) (2*)
```

I want to add sources paths in `Target` (1) lists as variable `set(SRC my_src.cpp)` and headers paths in `Target` (1) lists as variable `set(HEADERS my_header.hpp)`

But by default clion adds paths in (2) into `add_executable()` function

Am i able to override that behaviour or it's impossible?

P.S. (2) includes (1) in the place i need to get those variables

Comment: If you use "New C++ Class" then you can't split where the source and header files are put. You have to create the source and header files separately, in which case you can select which executable target you want to add them to. Perhaps you need to rethink the layout of your project and the `CMakeLists.txt` files?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can't change layout because it's game framework's layout. I tried to add separately but there wasn't my file in list

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but there shouldn't be any need to have a list of header files.   Why are you creating one?